# ActiveAdmin Scope buttons orientation and style

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin

I created scopes for my model in ActiveAdmin, The issue is that they overlap each other and it looks messy. I would like to know if it's possible to move the scope buttons from the top of the page to a sidebar menu or fix the alignment. If it's possible, how do I do this?

[Here is a pic of My Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvr1J.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could tacke:

1. You create your own css file that would overlap the css classes for those elements in activeadmin.scss. I.e. if the menu  tag is listed horizontally, you move it to vertically, or add more spacing, etc.
2. You can create your own html partial and render your admin menu items inside it, giving you more flexibility to structure the html as you see fit.

Here is a useful link on activeadmin custom pages:

https://activeadmin.info/8-custom-actions.html#rendering

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solve my issue by editing the active_admin.scss stylesheet.                                                           
I used: [" body.active_admin .table_tools a "] to reference the scope buttons in the stylesheet.